# Lumen surface from boundary points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, surface

I want to ask about surface construction from given 3D boundary points.
I have extracted vessel from 3D volume as shown in RED color, whereas the reference data provided is in form of 3D point set (vertices) representing the lumen behaviour at certain points shown in black colour.

I just want to connect all these contours to obtain a surface representing the tubular vessel (like RED vessel in below figure) so that I could calculate the Overlapping volume.

If I am able to get mesh representation of Black pointcloud, Still I can perform voxelization from mesh to obtain binary volume but at the moment I am stuck with this ...

[image]

Comment: you say you can perform voxelization of the mesh, why not use that?

Comment: At the moment, the reference data provided by Organizers  (shown in Black) contain only Vertices information i.e. set of 3D points only whereas faces=0.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a mesh of those points and then convert to binary.